# Validate a gml file

Tags: qgis, gml

I receive a gml-like response from a RESTful Web service. It looks good for me but I can not imported in QGIS. Is there an online validation tool for a valid gml file? Or am I missing something for the schema?

The response I received is as

```xml
<Polygons>
  <DriveTime duration="30">
    <Polygon>
      <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
          <posList>41.0296010971069 -73.9398550987244 41.0188937187195 -73.9155864715576 41.0581398010254 -73.8332319259644 41.017370223999 -73.8251423835754 40.9897971153259 -73.7459421157837 40.9789824485779 -73.6955809593201 40.9320545196533 -73.7493538856506 40.862123966217 -73.8021397590637 40.8192944526672 -73.8084053993225 40.8174920082092 -73.8013029098511 40.8047890663147 -73.6684370040894 40.7836532592773 -73.5890650749207 40.7572603225708 -73.6199641227722 40.7433986663818 -73.6648964881897 40.7084226608276 -73.6869120597839 40.6833171844482 -73.6838436126709 40.6573748588562 -73.6869549751282 40.6232357025146 -73.7346339225769 40.6431698799133 -73.7853598594666 40.6136870384216 -73.8205289840698 40.6405091285706 -73.8775634765625 40.629415512085 -73.8853740692139 40.6116271018982 -73.897111415863 40.5840969085693 -73.9238047599792 40.5747413635254 -73.9734792709351 40.58349609375 -73.9834785461426 40.6026148796082 -74.015429019928 40.5769944190979 -74.0807676315308 40.5689263343811 -74.0921187400818 40.5981302261353 -74.1254639625549 40.6105327606201 -74.1812968254089 40.5980658531189 -74.2316579818726 40.6317758560181 -74.238395690918 40.680570602417 -74.2200064659119 40.6869649887085 -74.2736077308655 40.714066028595 -74.295859336853 40.7720446586609 -74.269380569458 40.8061408996582 -74.2862892150879 40.8088231086731 -74.290087223053 40.8478331565857 -74.2046213150024 40.8865427970886 -74.2311215400696 40.8948683738709 -74.2362928390503 40.9156179428101 -74.1825199127197 40.9354877471924 -74.133939743042 40.950014591217 -74.1370940208435 40.9720087051392 -74.080445766449 40.9833598136902 -74.0716052055359 40.9472250938416 -73.9906239509583 40.9620308876038 -73.9610767364502 41.0296010971069 -73.9398550987244</posList>
        </LinearRing>
      </exterior>
    </Polygon>
  </DriveTime>
</Polygons>
```

Comment: looks like it's missing some header lines that define the schema (I'd usually expect Polygons and Polygon to be in different namespaces).

Comment: I think this is generated by sql server. But I really have difficulties to use this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GML validator at opengeospatial.org for GML 2.1.2:
http://cite.opengeospatial.org/test_engine/gml/2.1.2/validator/

You must paste your code into the Instance document field.  They do not seem to have a validator available for GML 3.x.x.

**Edit 2021**: On the new website at https://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/ one can also find test suites for [GML 3.2](https://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/about/gml32/3.2.1/site/). Sadly, it can only be run locally.