# Consuming gml generated by sql server As.GML()

Tags: qgis, sql-server, gml

Sql server has a method [As.GML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933989.aspx) to produce GML file from geography/geometric type. Is there a good example to utilize this GML on other mapping platform such as QGIS? I have ask a related question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/validate-a-gml-file), but QGIS reports its format is not valid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up write my own parser in python to parse the polygon string returned by sql server. Note that the `simplekml` library and the `xml.etree` library are used.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import simplekml

def ParsexmlString(xmlstring):
    rxml = ElementTree.fromstring(xmlstring)
    drivetime = rxml.find('./Polygons/').get('duration')
    polygonstring = rxml.findtext('./[Your Polygon Location]}Polygon/{http://www.opengis.net/gml}exterior/{http://www.opengis.net/gml}LinearRing/{http://www.opengis.net/gml}posList')
    polygonlist= polygonstring.split(' ')
    polygonlist = [float(i) for i in polygonlist] 
    polygonlist = list(zip(*(iter(polygonlist),) * 2))
    polygonlist2 = [(i[1],i[0]) for i in polygonlist]
    return (polygonlist2)

def AddPolygontoKml(multiplekml, counter, polygonlist):
    multiplekml.newpolygon(name="Store Number " +str(counter),outerboundaryis=polygonlist)

    return (multiplekml)
```

Answer (score 0):

QGIS is reading GML data with GDAL which wants to find the geometries inside gml:FeatureCollection as you can see from the example of the driver manual page http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gml.html

Another example about GML that GDAL understands can be captured from this WFS server
[http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=osm:water_areas&outputformat=gml3&maxfeatures=1](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=osm%3awater_areas&outputformat=gml3&maxfeatures=1)

I fear that for parsing GML like in your sample a special QGIS plugin would be needed.